# How to get the computed value of a CSS variable in Playwright?

Tags: playwright, css-variables

I'm trying to use Playwright to test an Ionic React app.

[Ionic makes extensive use of CSS variables.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables)

My app allows users to change some of these colors, so I want to verify the color changes work properly.

I am trying to find a way to test the value of the CSS variable.

The Ionic CSS looks like this:

```
ion-header ion-toolbar {
  --background: var(--ion-color-secondary);
}
```

How can I get the value of `--background` with Playwright?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4282#issuecomment-718602677) describes how to use `getPropertyValue()` to get the value of a CSS property.  This will also return the computed result for CSS variables:

```
  const navBar = await page.locator('ion-header ion-toolbar >> visible=true');
  const color = await navBar.evaluate((element) =>
    window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('--background'),
  );
```